# ndbcluster tables gone invisible after mysql cluster restart

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

I did create a local mysql cluster few days back and started converting some of my existing innodb tables to ndb storage engines in order to check cluster's functioning. This process was working find and I was able to see those ndb tables on other nodes as well. Though, When I restarted mysql cluster by shutting down all mysqld processes and management process and then restarted them back, NDB tables are missing and I have no clue about them. Here is my cluster config details.

```
Connected to Management Server at: localhost:1186
Cluster Configuration
---------------------
[ndbd(NDB)] 2 node(s)
id=2    @127.0.0.1  (mysql-5.6.24 ndb-7.4.6, Nodegroup: 0, *)
id=3    @127.0.0.1  (mysql-5.6.24 ndb-7.4.6, Nodegroup: 0)

[ndb_mgmd(MGM)] 1 node(s)
id=1    @127.0.0.1  (mysql-5.6.24 ndb-7.4.6)

[mysqld(API)]   3 node(s)
id=4    @127.0.0.1  (mysql-5.6.24 ndb-7.4.6)
id=5    @127.0.0.1  (mysql-5.6.24 ndb-7.4.6)
id=6    @127.0.0.1  (mysql-5.6.24 ndb-7.4.6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks you Guys !

I got my answer. I was starting ndbd process with --initial which was causing data files cleaning hence no ndb data was visible after restart. I did create an ndb table again and restarted mysql cluster but this time restarted data nodes without --initial (simply using ndbd after starting management node).